# Creating a BMI calculator in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a code that will calculate the BMI of a person, and I have provided an option to the user to enter they gender from the options provided.

If the user selects some other option I want the program to quit and it does as expected, however when a user selects the right option `Male` or `Female` program is quitting and not going to next line asking for `user_weight`:

```
enter_gender = input("please enter the gender Male / Female: ")
if enter_gender .lower() not in ("Male", "Female"):
    quit()
user_weight = float(input("please enter your weight: "))
user_height = float(input("please enter your height in centimeters: "))/100
square_height = (user_height*user_height)
BMI = user_weight//square_height
print(f"your current BMI is {BMI}")
if BMI < 12:
    print("You are BMI is below ")
elif BMI < 25:
    print("Your are Healthy")
elif BMI <= 30:
    print("print over weight")
```

Answer (score 0):

Any string converted to lowercase cannot be equal to either `Male` or `Female`. Change it to:

```
if enter_gender.lower() not in ("male", "female"):
```

As a side note, you don't seem to be taking the gender into account later in your code.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are checking an impossible condition

It is either you check **if enter_gender not in ("Male", "Female"):** if you want the user to enter **Male** or **Female**

or you check **if enter_gender.lower() not in ("male", "female"):** if you want the user to enter **male** or **female**

or you can remove the conditional check completely because it doesn't seem you are using it

```
enter_gender = input("please enter the gender Male / Female: ")
**if enter_gender not in ("Male", "Female"):**
    quit()
user_weight = float(input("please enter your weight: "))
user_height = float(input("please enter your height in centimeters: "))/100
square_height = (user_height*user_height)
BMI = user_weight//square_height
print(f"your current BMI is {BMI}")
if BMI < 12:
    print("You are BMI is below ")
elif BMI < 25:
    print("Your are Healthy")
elif BMI <= 30:
    print("print over weight")
```